# Converting to Eastern Time Zone (North America)

Tags: java, time, jodatime

I have this piece of code for a client in Eastern time zone:

```
public DateTime getActivityDate() {
    return new DateTime(activityDate, DateTimeZone.UTC).minusHours(5);
}
```

The client was reporting it was working until the time change back in November. Now they are reporting they are seeing the times as " 1 hour ahead of Eastern time zone."

Is there any way I can get this working for both davelight savings time and standard time instead of hardcoding it as minusHours(5) and minusHours(6)?

Comment: There are [at least 4 timezones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EST#Time) which use the abbreviation "EST". Don't use three-letter abbreviations, use IANA abbreviations, like "America/New York".

Comment: One thing is strange. How do you justify to subtract 5 or SIX hours when speaking about Eastern time zone? New York - time has offsets either -05 or -04 but not -06. Other zones mentioned in link given by @Andy Turner are even completely off for the offsets you want.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, please use the appropriate timezone identifier for New York - time:

```
return new DateTime(activityDate, DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York"));
```

By the way: **It is a wrong idea to do time arithmetic like `minusHours(5)` here in order to take tz offsets into account.** What you are doing, is also changing the instant/moment given by `activityDate` and not just changing the local representation in appropriate timezone. Example showing the difference between your code and my proposal:

```
System.out.println(new DateTime(new Date(), DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York"))); 
// 2016-12-19T11:05:58.507-05:00

System.out.println(new DateTime(new Date(), DateTimeZone.UTC).minusHours(5)); 
// 2016-12-19T11:05:58.573Z
```

We have same "local" representations but different offsets (-05 versus Z=+00) resulting in different instants. Only my proposal yields correct local time (for New York) AND correct instant.

Comment: Wouldn't I still have to hardcode the  minus 5 or 6 hours for this though?

Comment: @Mdjon26 Oh no, don't use hard-coding. The given zone will automatically convert given `activityDate` to a proper local representation within `DateTime`, either UTC-05 (in winter) or UTC-04 (in summer). No further action needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using org.joda.time.DateTime :

```
public static final DateTime getEasternUSLocalDateTime(DateTime pDateTimeUtc) {

    // Convert the Date
    DateTime convertedDate  = originalDate.withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York"));
    // Return the localTime associated with the timeZone
    return convertedDate.toLocalDateTime();
}
```

Comment: This looks good, but how I am a little confused on how exactly I can do this for Eastern time zone?

Comment: The question of OP mentions a method to return `DateTime`, not `Date`.

Comment: And this is for Eastern for America (as in New York)

Comment: Edited to return correct DateTime and with Eastern Europe Timezone